# UnicodeDecodeError in using StanfordParser for parsing tweets

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to parse a stream of tweets using the StanfordParser with caseless English model (englishPCFG.caseless.ser.gz), mentioned in the FAQs: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#ca. I encountered the following error while calling the raw_parse method:

```
import nltk
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser
parser = StanfordParser(
                      path_to_jar="stanford-parser.jar" \
                    , path_to_models_jar="stanford-corenlp-caseless-2014-02-25-models.jar" \
                    , model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.caseless.ser.gz"
                    , encoding='utf-8'
                    )
tweet = 'Good News™: The weather is going to be awesome today for some ultimate.'
tweet_unicode = unicode(tweet, 'UTF-8')
parser.raw_parse(tweet_unicode)

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-71163f9030ad> in <module>()
----> 1 parser.raw_parse_sents(sentence)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.pyc in raw_parse_sents(self, sentences, verbose)
    174             '-outputFormat', 'penn',
    175         ]
--> 176         return self._parse_trees_output(self._execute(cmd, '\n'.join(sentences), verbose))
    177 
    178     def tagged_parse(self, sentence, verbose=False):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.pyc in _execute(self, cmd, input_, verbose)
    235             stdout, stderr = java(cmd, classpath=(self._stanford_jar, self._model_jar),
    236                                   stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
--> 237             stdout = stdout.decode(encoding)
    238 
    239         os.unlink(input_file.name)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc in decode(input, errors)
     14 
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 
     18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 56: invalid start byte
```

For most other tweets containing special characters, the method works fine; however in this particular case, it fails due to the trademark character. Any pointers on how to resolve this? Examining the source code of the parser file, it looks like the error occurs while reading from a temporary file created by the parser.

And, more generally, how to ensure most characters in English are accounted for?

Comment: AFAICS, there is no problem with the Stanford Parser's output on this tweet. It seems to be a problem with the Python wrapper. So, I've added the nltk tag....

Comment: What encoding do you use for the source file?  That doesn't look like a valid UTF-8 string, so you are probably turning it into something ... awful.  Try with `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and a `u"...."` string to mark it as Unicode in and of itself, then do away with the encoding/decoding stuff.